# Unable to see partition after installing Mint

Tags: linux-mint, grub2

I installed Linux Mint 17 on a partition on my (Lenovo y40) laptop which had Windows 8.1 preinstalled (I had to enable Legacy boot in order to get past the blank screen using the bootable USB). Now, I can't find a way to access that installation of Mint. I have used programs like EasyBCD to create the grub loader screen in the past but it does not see the partition either.

Comment: Did you create a Legacy, EFI or UEFI partition? Basically, did you use `parted` or did you use `fdisk`? And what size disk is it?

Comment: I created the partition in Windows, which I think creates an EFI partition by default (? I'm not sure). My parent disk was 900 Gb and I created a 50 Gb partition.

Comment: With less then 2 Tb, it's probably a MBR partition.